# DataTrigger breaks the previous one

Tags: wpf, datatrigger

There are two DataTriggers. Right after launching application both triggers work, but after second trigger fires the first doesn't work anymore. How to fix this problem?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ButDown,Path=IsPressed}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" By="20" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>                
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ButUp,Path=IsPressed}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" By="-20" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="ButUp">UP</Button>
    <Button x:Name="ButDown">DOWN</Button>
    <TextBlock Margin="100">TextBlock</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```